# numpy/scipy equivalent of MATLAB's SYMAMD function

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm working on porting some MATLAB code into Python but wasn't able to locate an equivalent function in numpy or scipy for SYMAMD.

A partial description of the function in MATLAB:

```
SYMAMD Symmetric approximate minimum degree permutation.
    P = SYMAMD(S) for a symmetric positive definite matrix S, returns the
    permutation vector p such that S(p,p) tends to have a sparser Cholesky
    factor than S.
```

Anyone aware of an equivalent function? I was going to attempt to port the C code from the author's website at http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse, but I would rather not.